# Safety Relay Coil resistance

Tags: relay, datasheet

I have a Dold Safety relay OA5621[OA5621 data sheet](http://www.dold.com.cn/uploadfiles/OA5621.pdf) on page 2 of the data sheet it lists standard variants:

I have a 24 volt relay, OA5621.52 with 2NO/2NC contacts. I can't figure out what Rsp means, is it the contact resistance or coil resistance?

I need to find the coil resistance, is it 3753 ohms or 960 ohms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coil resistance is 960 Ω, which is consistent with the nominal voltage (24 V) and power (0.6 W). R = V<sup>2</sup>/P.

I have no idea what those other columns are about.

Answer (score 1):

Rsp is the coil resistance. Note that the relationship between coil voltage and Rsp gives the same power consumption for all voltages. I believe that 3753 is the "Design version" that you need when determining the complete part number.